# Strftime error Python

Tags: python, django, strftime

I'm calling a function to get the calculation for driver revenue but, I keep getting this error:

```
"line 396, in driver_get_revenue
    monthly[month.strftime("%m")] = orders.count() * settings.DRIVER_DELIVERY_PRICE
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'strftime'"
```

The function is this:

```
def driver_get_revenue(request):

        driver = JWTAuthentication().authenticate(request)[0].driver


        #Returns the difference between date and time.
        from datetime import timedelta

        revenue = {}
        monthly = {}
        yearly = {}


        today = timezone.now()
        month = today.month
        year = today.year


        #Created a range to calculate the current weekday.
        current_weekdays = [today + timedelta(days = i) for i in range(0 - today.weekday(), 7 - today.weekday())]

        for day in current_weekdays:
            orders = Order.objects.filter(
                driver = driver,
                status = Order.DELIVERED,
                created_at__year = day.year,
                created_at__month = day.month,
                created_at__day = day.day
            )
            revenue[day.strftime("%A")] = orders.count() * settings.DRIVER_DELIVERY_PRICE




        for day in range(0, 30):
            orders = Order.objects.filter(
                    driver = driver,
                    status = Order.DELIVERED,
                    created_at__month = month,
                    created_at__day = day
                )

          (Line 396)  monthly[month.strftime("%m")] = orders.count() * settings.DRIVER_DELIVERY_PRICE




        for month in range(0, 12):
            orders = Order.objects.filter(
                    driver = driver,
                    status = Order.DELIVERED,
                    created_at__year = year,
                    created_at__month = month

                )

        yearly[year.strftime("%y")] = orders.count() * settings.DRIVER_DELIVERY_PRICE

        return JsonResponse({"revenue": revenue,
                            "month": monthly,
                            "yearly": yearly})
```

I'm not exactly sure where I went wrong. I marked line 396 so that you see where the error is. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: You don't need `strftime` at all here; `month` is already the integer month.

Answer (score 1):

When you do this: `month = today.month`, month becomes an integer. The `strftime` function works with datetime objects, not with integers.

Therefore, `month.strftime("%m")` doesn't work.

Try `day.strftime("%m")` instead, or perhaps just `month`, depending on your requirements.

If instead you're looking for the month's name, you could do it like this:

```
today = timezone.now()
month = today.month
month_name = today.strftime("%B") # e.g. December
...
```

...and use the `month_name` variable in your code.

Comment: I'm looking for the month name to come back.